# What are the variables in my cucumber feature for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tdd, cucumber

I have an application that I am looking at and I have this code

```
Feature: Contact us
    In order to allow users to contact us for help with the site
    As a user of the site
    I want to be able to view contact information

    @code-GGTU @estimate-1
    Scenario: Contact us page
        Given I am a logged in user
        When I follow "Contact Us"
        Then I should see "Contacts" in "main"
```

What is the `@code-GGTU @estimate-1` portion used for....it there documentation of special meaning for these variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These variables are 'tags', which help cucumber decide which options to use when it executes the scenario.  You can see documentation about this here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags

Comment: do you know off hand how to declare them

Comment: You need to declare them in your support/env.rb file there should be an example there

Comment: I've never heard of any need to declare tags - can you expand on this?